# AWS EC2 instance - Cannot assign EIP to EC2 instance w/ more than 1 interface

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When I try to launch an EC2 instance with 2 interfaces (2 subnets), I get an error and "Auto-assign Public IP" is Disabled.

[image]

What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to assign a Public IP address to an Amazon EC2 instance:

- **At startup ("Auto-Assign a Public IP"):** This is the option you chose. A public IP address will be assigned. If the instance is stopped and started, the public IP address *might* change.
- **An Elastic IP Address:** The public IP address will remain the same. You can also reassign the address to a different instance. You keep the public IP address until you specifically *release* it.

Based on your screenshot, it appears that the first option is not a valid means of assigning a public IP address to an instance with multiple network interfaces. Therefore:

- **Launch** your instance *without* a public IP address
- Create an **Elastic IP address**
- **Assign** the Elastic IP address to one of the interfaces on the Amazon EC2 instance

Comment: Thank you! I used "Associate address" and selected "interface-id" and it worked! If I associate by "instance", I get the same error. I don't really understand the logic behind it!

Comment: An Elastic IP address is mapped to a private IP address. If you have more than one interface, you need to specify which one should receive the Elastic IP address. (If the above answer has solved your Question, you can indicate this by clicking the checkmark.)

Comment: Thank you. I have accepted this as the answer. I am just not understanding why it would not assign EIP when I provision an instance. It would not even let me associate the EIP by selecting instance + interface. It only works when I use interface-id (which require some additional work to figure it out)

Comment: You can associate an Elastic IP address by selecting either Instance or ENI. If you select an Instance, you also need to select the Private IP address to which the Elastic IP address should forward traffic.